# Aggregating if each observation can belong to multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I want to aggregate Date by group. However, each observation can belong to several groups (e.g. observation 1 belongs to group A and B). I could not find a nice way to achieve this with `data.table`. Currently I created for each of the possible groups a logical variable which takes the value `TRUE` if the observation belongs to that group. I am looking for a better way to do this than presented below. I would also like to know how I could achieve this with the `tidyverse`.

```
library(data.table)
# Data
set.seed(1)
TF <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
time <- rep(1:4, each = 5)
df <- data.table(time = time, x = rnorm(20), groupA = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                                             groupB = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                                             groupC = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE))

# This should be nicer and less repetitive
df[groupA == TRUE, .(A = sum(x)), by = time][
  df[groupB == TRUE, .(B = sum(x)), by = time], on = "time"][
    df[groupC == TRUE, .(C = sum(x)), by = time], on = "time"]

# desired output
time          A          B         C
1:    1         NA  0.9432955 0.1331984
2:    2  1.2257538  0.2427420 0.1882493
3:    3 -0.1992284 -0.1992284 1.9016244
4:    4  0.5327774  0.9438362 0.9276459
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
df[, lapply(.SD[, .(groupA, groupB, groupC)]*x, sum), time]
# > df[, lapply(.SD[, .(groupA, groupB, groupC)]*x, sum), time]
#    time     groupA     groupB    groupC
# 1:    1  0.0000000  0.9432955 0.1331984
# 2:    2  1.2257538  0.2427420 0.1882493
# 3:    3 -0.1992284 -0.1992284 1.9016244
# 4:    4  0.5327774  0.9438362 0.9276459
```

or (thx to @chinsoon12 for the comment) more programmatically:

```
df[, lapply(.SD*x, sum), by=.(time), .SDcols=paste0("group", c("A","B","C"))]
```

If you want the result in the long format you can do:

```
df[, colSums(.SD*x), by=.(time), .SDcols=paste0("group", c("A","B","C"))]
### with indicator for the group:
df[, .(colSums(.SD*x), c("A","B","C")), by=.(time), .SDcols=paste0("group", c("A","B","C"))]
```

Comment: +1 sweet! and also more programmatically: `df[, lapply(.SD*x, sum), by=.(time), .SDcols=paste0("group", c("A","B","C"))]`

Comment: Nice solution. However, if I run your code for a long format output the group variable is missing. How could this be fixed?

Comment: @jogo Could you possibly take a look at my follow up question to this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487229/aggregating-if-each-observation-can-belong-to-multiple-groups-with-multiple-grou?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier here to work in long format. First I gather the observations to long format, then keep only the values where the observation belongs to the corresponding group. Then I remove the logical column, and rename the groups to single letters. Then I aggregate across groups and time (summarise in `dplyr`).
Finally I spread back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
TF <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
time <- rep(1:4, each = 5)


df <- data.frame(time = time, x = rnorm(20), groupA = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                 groupB = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                 groupC = sample(TF, size = 20, replace = TRUE))


df %>% 
  gather(group, belongs, groupA:groupC) %>% 
  filter(belongs) %>% 
  select(-belongs) %>% 
  mutate(group = gsub("group", "", group)) %>% 
  group_by(time, group) %>% 
  summarise(x = sum(x)) %>% 
  spread(group, x)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   time [4]
   time       A      B     C
  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  NA      0.943 0.133
2     2   1.23   0.243 0.188
3     3  -0.199 -0.199 1.90 
4     4   0.533  0.944 0.928
```

Answer (score 1):

An option can be using `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages in combination with `data.table`. Try to work on data in long format and then change it to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

melt(df, id.vars = c("time", "x")) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  group_by(time, variable) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(x)) %>%
  spread(variable, sum)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups: time [4]
# time  groupA groupB groupC
# * <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1  NA      0.943  0.133
# 2     2   1.23   0.243  0.188
# 3     3 - 0.199 -0.199  1.90 
# 4     4   0.533  0.944  0.928
```